# Forms with multiple conditional and multiple rows

Tags: 7, forms

What modules can I best accomplish a form that required conditionals

(i.e. choose radio button 1 and these sets of fields are displayed)

But as well, supporting multiple rows (i.e. a collection of name, phone, email) that can be duplicated and entered more than once?

There are a couple of choices, Inline Entity Form, Webform, Entityforms... What modules would you recommend, or is it better writing a custom solution?

Comment: better, write custom code, on all changeable elements add ajax callback and on callback function show/hide or add/remove elements and  rebuild the form .

Comment: Write your own custom module.